# How to methodically compare random elements in list - Java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a TicTacToe program in Java. The grid for the tics is coded as

```
String[] board = new String[9]
```

With this, I have a separate class that takes the board and determines the best possible move. For starters, I decided that if the opponent has 2 in a row/column/diagonal, then the computer should place the symbol in the next space in that row/column/diagonal.

Here is my starter code to do that:

```
String[][] threes = new String[8][3];
    for (String[] arr: threes) {
        // Compare the elements of arr to figure out how to block opponent
    }
```

As you can see by the comment in the code, is there any way to quickly determine in Java the following except for each possible case of having 2 elements of one kind (X or O) and one not filled:

```
if ((arr[0].equals(arr[1])) && !(arr[1].equals(arr[2]))) {
    return arr[2];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: *Unrelated:* Incorrect "For starters", because first priority would be to check if *computer* has 2 in a row/column/diagonal, so it can place winning move.

Comment: I would suggest you create an `int[8][3]` with the index positions of the 8 "lines" on the board, i.e. `final int[][] idx = { {0,1,2}, {3,4,5}, {6,7,8}, {0,3,6}, {1,4,7}, {2,5,8}, {0,4,8}, {2,4,6} }`, so you can use it to iterate through the lines. You can then iterate through lines: `for (int[] ix : idx) { int xCount = 0; for (int i : ix) { if (board[i].equals("X") { xCount++; } ) } /* use xCount here */ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this particular problem, I would change your model to store `int` values, and use `-1` for “O”, `+1` for “X”, and 0 for blank.

Then, if you sum any line, you will get:

- +3 or -3 for a “win”, and
- +2 or -2 for an unblocked 2-in-a-row

Your view would be responsible for turning -1 and +1 into the correct X/O symbols, and your controller would turn the symbols into the appropriate value to store in the model.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help